# How to convert my XML code to Log4j.properties?

Tags: java, xml, log4j

How to convert my XMl code to Log4j properties?

Kindly guide me to reach the best tutorials on this. I had googled a lot and i could find only about to converting Log4l properties to XML but not from XML to Log4j.properties.

please guide me to finish it out.

Thank you.

My XML code to be converted to log4j.properties

```
<appender name="ErrorEmailAppender"  
class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
<param name="SMTPHost" value="mail.mydomain.com" />
<param name="SMTPUsername" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
<param name="SMTPPassword" value="password" />
<param name="From" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
<param name="To" value="myuser@mydomain.com" />
<param name="Subject" value="Log of messages" />
<param name="BufferSize" value="1" />
<param name="EvaluatorClass" value="TriggerLogEvent" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %m%n"/>
</layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.foo.mailer">
<level value="INFO" />
<appender-ref ref="ErrorEmailAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Thank you

Comment: As far as i could find, there is no automated way of doing that. Most people i know had to do this manually :(